# Forgot encrypted LVM passphrase but am logged in

Tags: encryption, lvm

I have a machine running 16.04 which needs a reboot and has been running for a few months now. I was about to reset when I realized I can't remember the encrypted LVM passphrase. If I reboot it, I will be locked out.

I can log into the machine just fine and have sudo permissions, just can't reboot. Is there any way to circumvent this? I have the `Disks` utility and am attempting to add a new passphrase but it won't let me do so without the current one, which I obviously don't remember.

Comment: There is NO known way to circumvent the encryption passphrase. (That's the point of using encryption!) Preserve your data now, while you have access to it.

Comment: I am glad you remembered the password and it worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Backup! Backup!! Backup!!!

Backup your data in an external drive. Then make a second copy of everything you value in a second external drive.

## Reinstall Ubuntu

Install Ubuntu as before. Use the option to erase existing Ubuntu and install.

## Password Manager

Use a password manager such as KeepassXC to store your pass-phrase. There are Android and iOS apps for Keepass and other password manager. You may want to sync the password database into multiple devices and computers so that you can access forgotten password from different devices.

Hope this helps

Comment: After a few wasted hours of guessing I actually somehow jogged my memory and remembered it, but I'll be looking into a manager to prevent this in the future. Thanks!